# An error occurred when GA4 links to BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I want to use **GA4** (free version) links to **BigQuery**.

My **GCP IAM**:

- BigQuery Data Owner
- BigQuery Job User

However, I get the error as following:

[image]

This error message is not detailed enough that I don't know how to solve...

Anyone know a possible reason for the error?

Thanks in advance!

---

##### Edited

**Now, I suspect the error reason is VPC Network.**

If True, there're any possiblility can integrate GA4 with BQ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error comes from `VPC Network`, the solution is:

1. First, remove `VPC Network`
2. Connect GA4 with BQ
3. Enable `VPC Network`
4. Enable the `access manager api`
5. Allow the `access level` for GA4 service account.